# How to upload an entire hard drive of photos into Google+ Photos?

Tags: photos, google-plus

I have a ton of photos (50GB+) that I would like to upload into Google+ Photos. Using the upload tool is very painful, as I have to go into each folder and drag and drop the pictures into the upload dialog and pray that the browser doesn't crash. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

See if the Picasa software (picasa.google.com) can handle what you want to do. The folders created by Picasa on the server are linked to the Google+ side of the world.

Comment: I think it does, I don't use it any more but there is an ability to set defaults for syncing photos to the web and at least click in each folder of pictures and mark it for syncing.